# Save programm output to file and include the actual time and date in the filename

Tags: command-line, command, debian

I like to create a kind of simple error log for a python program which runs on startup (through rc.local on a raspberry). Since I like to use this for debuging my files, the error logs should include date and time in their name.

This is what I got:

```
sudo python myprogram.py> /home/pi/errorlogs/myprogram.txt 2>&1
```

So far so good - but: How can I include the actual time and date in "myprogram.txt" (so it becomes lets say "myprogramm_2014-02-10_19:45:00.txt") and is not deleted any time I reboot? I played around with .strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M"). but didn´t get it to work.

Not really perfect is the fact, that I do not get a continuous output in my file - that is something I could life with since I dont need them during the run - but maybe there is a whole different approach for what I need anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just let the shell do that for you.

```
sudo python myprogram.py> /home/pi/errorlogs/myprogram-$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M).txt 2>&1
```